# cannot delete an object in database using doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

Hi I am starting to use doctrine and I have some problems with remove function.
Here is my code

```
$us = User::findAll();

User::remove($us);
```

In the user class I have

```
    public static function findAll()
{
    return self::getRepository()->findAll();
}
```

and

```
    public static function remove($obj)
{
    global $em;
    try {
        $em->remove($obj);
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What are "some problems"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of user object to remove, which expects a single object. Try the following:

```
public static function remove($objects) {
    global $em;
    try {
        foreach($objects as $obj) {
            $em->remove($obj);
        }
        $em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return true;
}
```

You should not just drop the message of an exception, it provides additional debug information.

Comment: @Alireza Glad I could help. Please mark the answer accordingly.